# Embed Google Maps - Difference between Google Maps Embed API and Share a map - Embed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Embed Google Maps - Difference between Google Maps Embed API and Share a map - Embed

I need to embed a Google Map Place in my web Application. I can see two options:

1. Google Maps Embed API -
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start
2. Google
   Maps Share Location Embed -
   https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

What is the difference between the two with respect to usage in a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) have a few features which are not available with [Google Maps Share Location Embed](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) like highlighting places and tracking the usage of the API(e.g. how many times the map was loaded), while the Share a map is mostly customized for each user:

> When you view the map on your site, you'll see your saved places on
>   the map(saved on your gmail account).
>
> Your site's visitors won't see those saved places – they'll see a map
>   built for them.

If you are building a site that will be used by the public, I would suggest that you use the Embed API, this will also help you monitor the volume of the visitors of your site.